# Como encontrar um caraceter na string e recortar string até ele e depois dele

Tags: php

Estou tentando, sem sucesso fazer um recorte de uma string a partir de um caractere contido nela, primeiramente preciso encontrar o `_` na string, depois de encontra-lo preciso recortar a mesma até ele e depois dele até o `ponto`, se não encontrar o caractere preciso recortar a string até o ponto.
Segue o que já tentei até o momento;

Encontrando o caractere na string:

```
$ID = '3803_452.jpg';
$termo = '_';

$padrao = '/' . $termo . '/';

if (preg_match($padrao, $ID)) {

  echo 'Tag encontrada';

} else {

  echo 'Tag não encontrada';

}
```

Se não existir o `_` preciso recortar a string até o ponto jogando em uma variável, ficando assim:

```
$Id = 3803
```

Se foi encontrado o `_` preciso recortar a string até ele e depois dele até o ponto jogando cada um em uma variável.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
$Id = 3803;
$Seq = 452;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer um split/explode por esse caractere, e assim ficas com a string separada. Depois usas `substr` para limitar a segunda parte até ao `.`.

```
$ID = '3803_452.jpg';
$partes = explode('_', $ID);

$id = $partes[0];
$seq = $partes[1];
$seq = substr($seq, 0, strpos($seq, '.'));
echo $id; // 3803
echo $seq; // 452
```

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/VClG5Y

Outra alternativa, mais semântica (corrigindo [um problema que o Everson levantou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243138/como-encontrar-um-caraceter-na-string-e-recortar-string-at%C3%A9-ele-e-depois-dele/243139?noredirect=1#comment498190_243139)) seria trabalhar só com o `substr`:

```
$ID = '3803_452.jpg';

$id = substr($ID, 0, strpos($ID, '_'));
$seq = substr($ID, strlen($id) + 1, strpos($ID, '.') - strlen($id) - 1);
if (strlen($id) == 0) {
    $id = $seq;
    $seq = '';
}

echo $id; // 3803
echo '<>';
echo $seq; // 452
```

**Ideone**: https://ideone.com/smqebV

Comment: Olá @Sérgio, bom dia, agradeço a ajuda, vou alterar a pergunta, não preciso do .jpg da string, somente os valores.

Comment: @adventistapr isso estava claro na pergunta. Eu é que não tinha reparado bem e agora já corrigi.

Comment: Agradeço a grande ajuda.

Comment: O `$seq = substr($seq, 0, strpos($seq, '.'));` pode ser feito direto no `$ID` já que é uma parte que não interessa. E também que a restrição da pergunta se aplica **se não encontrar o caractere preciso recortar a string até o ponto**, então não haverá `$partes[1]` isso gerá um warning no PHP

Comment: @Everson bem visto! Corrigi, obrigado!

Comment: @MagicHat tens razão. Corrigi!

Comment: @MagicHat está a funcionar. Deve ser um problema de cache do Ideone. Tinha testado tirando o `_` e ele guardou esse `stdout`... Cliquei no Save outra vez e limpou.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar essa combinação de [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php) e [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php).

```
<?php
$str = '3803452.jpg';
$chars = preg_split('/_/', $str, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
if(count($chars) < 2)
{   $ext = pathinfo($str);
    $chars = $ext['filename'];
    echo $chars;
}else
{   echo $chars[0];
}
?>
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/5iDMnQ)